# Parsing Json Array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

Iam newbie in angularjs.How to display the json in html using angularjs.Below is the code

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/xyz").then(function (response) {

    });
});

Reponse is :

[
  {
    "city": "animal"
  },
  {
    "city": "bird"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you should assign your json to a scope:

```
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myArray = [];
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/xyz").then(function (response) {
        $scope.myArray = response;
    });
});
```

Then in your view, you can do something like:

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="obj in myArray">
        <li>{{obj.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-repeat` like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="t in test">
  <span>{{t.city}}</span>
</div>
```

[plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QS2f4gRCqqT3t01UxTel?p=preview)

Comment: In Plunker its displaying,but in my page its not displaying.I checked the JSON link twice its giving the reponse.But data is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code this might help you.

```
myArray = JSON.parse(response);

for ( var index in myArray ) {

var singleObject = myArray[index];
var keys = Object.keys[singleObject];
      for ( var j in keys ) {
            console.log("Value of key"+j+"is"+keys[j]+"in Object"+index);
      }
}
```

Here response is a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Where Records is like this..

```
{"records":[{"ID":"235","user_id":"2","project_id":"186","project_cid":"2900669120142632939","imagePath":"media/pano/sv_02a29.jpg","ImageName":"1.jpg"},{"ID":"236","user_id":"2","project_id":"186","project_cid":"2900669120142632939","imagePath":"media/pano/sv_f0f59.jpg","ImageName":"253.jpg"},{"ID":"239","user_id":"2","project_id":"186","project_cid":"1997319193267363957","imagePath":"media/pano/sv_6536f.jpg","ImageName":"PANOCLOUD_meta.jpg"},{"ID":"240","user_id":"2","project_id":"186","project_cid":"6736594884768838469","imagePath":"media/pano/sv_898ca.jpg","ImageName":"Boscolo Hotel Budapest.jpg"}]}



$http.get("moderatorData.php").then(function (response) {
                $scope.panoramas = response.data.records;
            });
```

Then print using like this

```
<li class="align" ng-repeat="pano in panoramas>
<img ng-src="{{pano.imagePath}}"  style="height: 90px;" />
</li>
```